# PHP BLOB image showing on website but cannot open it in new tab

Tags: php, encoding, blob

I'm displaying my BLOB image like this and it is working.

```
<img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.$row_img['image']; ?>" alt"" />
```

But when i try to copy image link and open it in url, it show me encrypted code like this :
ÿØÿà�JFIF��`�`��ÿÛ�C�ÿÛ�CÿÀ�6î"�ÿÄ�����������
ÿÄ�µ���}�!1AQa"q2‘¡#B±ÁRÑð$3br‚ 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyzƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š’“”•–—˜™š¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª²³´µ¶·¸¹ºÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚáâãäåæçèéêñòóôõö÷øùúÿÄ��������
ÿÄ�µ��w�!1AQaq"2B‘¡±Á   #3RðbrÑ.....

Comment: When you see text similar to the question it is not text but data bytes, that is when it is time to display as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the data url displayed as text, the browser doesn't know its a jpeg.
Add the correct mime type to the url and it should work

```
echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row_img['image'];
```

Comment: it works thank you but when i tried to share the page link on facebook, the image was not showing <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row_img['image']; ?>" />

Comment: I have serious doubts that a data uri will work with facebook share

Comment: thank for your help.I'll ask a new question for that

Answer (score 1):

Your content type for your data is wrong. `image` is not valid. It should be `image/png` or `image/jpeg` or something similar depending on the type of image.

From what you posted, it looks like your image is a JPEG.

Answer (score 1):

Because the browser has no way to know the mime type with inline image. Open them with img tag is Ok because you tell the browser it's an image. But without context in a new tab it s just a random string

EDIT : use a full correct mime

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub//ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7" alt"" />
```

Comment: thank you. but how can i get blob image type? beacause i'm displayin many images with differents types

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php read the full post and look for the alternative functions too

Comment: imo: you should be carefull with inline images because browsers have no way to put them in cache. maybe you should consider adding a dedicated controller to your software ? (but I don't know what you're doing so ;p)